# Why is a 250 Watt heat lamp over a shower going out after a few minutes?

Tags: lamp, heat

Heat Lamp goes out after approx 12-15 minutes, obviously getting hot.

could be lamp have a thermal coupling?

Seems I should be able to add a 250 watt on any circuit without damage.

Why is the light going out?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Who installed the heat lamp? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: You should also be specific about make/model of the heat lamp. One can speculate based on what's common operation of heat lamps generally, but only by knowing the exact model of heat lamp could anyone tell you for sure what might be going on.

Comment: Is the fixture *actually built from the ground up* to be a heat lamp fixture, or did you stick an incandescent heat lamp in a regular fixture?

Answer (score 1):

Most bathroom heater/lamps have timers to prevent fire (the lamp and housing get hot, not the wires) or accidentally running up a large electric bill. Turn the lamp off and then on again to reset it, *if* it's a timer. If it's a thermostatic safety device, you'll have to wait for it to cool.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a wet location fixture? Most fixtures over baths or showers are required to be damp or wet location rated. Many of these fixtures are only listed for 60w and the heat lamp is tripping a thermal safety.

Answer (score 0):

Can lights have thermal protectors, usually 125 to 135°F  https://amzn.to/2SgaGNZ , they sometimes fail, but more often the problem is insulation in contact with a non-IC rated fixture.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could have a loose neutral wire, which balances the load (amperage).

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It isn't clear what you mean; would you elaborate? And, props for [taking our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) before posting; most newbies don't.